# Is there any reliable way to define and cal functions on dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, function, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have a data frame containing consumer email data - fresh and repeat contact emails. I need to find outliers in this data based on certain conditions:

- condition 1: `count1 > 1` and `count 2 > 1`
- condition 2: `count1 > 1` and `count 2 < 1`

I have checked for function definition,syntax in python and accordingly defined a function for outlier classification.

```
def outlier():
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if([row][count1] > 1 and [row][count2] > 1):
            if(df[row][Journey] == df[row][journey_lag]):
                df[row][outlier] = Same_Property/Date/Agent/Journey
            else:
            df[row][outlier] = Same_Property/Date/Agent-Different Journey
        elif([row][count1] > 1 and [row][count2] == 1):
            if(df[row][Journey] == df[row][journey_lag]):
                df[row][outlier] = Same_Property/Date-Different_Agent/Journey
            else:
                df[row][outlier]=Same_Property/Date_Different_Agent/Journey
return df
```

I am expecting to execute this function with dataframe as follows:

```
df.outlier
df.apply(outlier)
```

> Error: Not able to get reqd results

Comment: You need to pass the data to process in your `outlier` function if you want to use it with `apply` [(doc)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). You can chose either row or column with `axis` argument if you iterate over rows or columns. Then you can apply it with the second line :  `df.apply(outlier)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.apply(my_function)` on a `DataFrame` objects, pandas will expect a 1-argument function, and this argument will be a column of the DataFrame if `axis=0`, a row of the DataFrame if `axis=1`.

You need something like this :

```
def outlier(row):
    if row['count1'] > 1 and row['count2'] > 1:
        if row['Journey'] == row['journey_lag']:
            return 'Same_Property/Date/Agent/Journey'
        else:
            return 'Same_Property/Date/Agent/Different_Journey'
    elif row['count1'] > 1 and row['count2'] == 1:
        if row['Journey'] == row['journey_lag']:
            return 'Same_Property/Date/Different_Agent/Journey'
        else:
            return 'Same_Property/Date/Different_Agent/Different_Journey'

df['outlier'] = df.apply(outlier, axis=1)
```